# Trouble creating headers with horizontal line going across

Tags: css

I want to create title that have an horizontal line going through them with the Title text appearing above the line, even though I believe I have correctly used the z-index rule it still does not work, this is the css I am using;

```
.heading {
border-bottom: 2px solid #222222!important;
text-align: center;
z-index: -1;
}

#sidebar .widget h3, #sidebar .widget .heading h3 {
color: #333333;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
margin-bottom: -8px;
position: relative;
}
```

The url is: http://crossfitblackboard.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
z-index
```

works only if you are using a `position`

so you need also set the `.heading` to `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep the markup as simple as possible; We can do this with one element for your heading and the pseudo element `:before` with `z-index: -1;`.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/bocuq/1/edit)

HTML

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}
h1:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    background: #F00;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0.6em;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a duplicate of the heading and `line-through` it.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="shadow">Your Awesome Heading</h1>
<h1>Your Awesome Heading</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
    position: absolute;
}

.shadow{
    color: lightgrey;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39rwmjt6/1/